# Why my label is truncating even though the number of lines is 0 and no height constraint?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a label and I added a attributed string to it. The string is,

```
let nameText = "My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer. My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer."`My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer. My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer.`
```

In this text I'm trying to add a `*` in the beginning of the text so I used an attributed string and the code looks like this,

```
func attributedTextForFeeApplies() -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "* " + nameText)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

    let superScriptString = "* "

    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, superScriptString.characters.count))
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9), range: NSMakeRange(0, superScriptString.characters.count))
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, superScriptString.characters.count))

    let superscriptAttributedString = attributedText
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    superscriptAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: NSMakeRange(0, superscriptAttributedString.length))

    return superscriptAttributedString
}
```

I gave the constraints to the Label like this,

[image]

Even though I set number of lines to `0` and no height constraint the label is truncating like this,
[image]

But when I don't use this line of code `attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, superScriptString.characters.count))` it is working fine like this,

[image]

And also if add `*` in the middle (without removing `attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, superScriptString.characters.count))`) it works fine but just doesn't work if I use it in the beginning of the text,

Screen shot:

[image]

And it also works if I increase the font size.

I think there is an issue with `NSAttributedString` and if not I want to know what is the issue. Could someone please help me.

Comment: beacuse of this let superscriptAttributedString = attributedText
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    superscriptAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: NSMakeRange(0, superscriptAttributedString.length)) your lable can put goes into number of lines

Comment: I didn't get what you said (your lable can put goes into number of lines?). Could you please elaborate.

Comment: NSMutableParagraphStyle that means your single line convert into multiple that so if you want to text im single line dont use NSMutableParagraphStyle .

Comment: just remove this line  let superscriptAttributedString = attributedText
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    superscriptAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: NSMakeRange(0, superscriptAttributedString.length)) and check your output

Comment: I implemented your suggestion with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is as soon as you assign attributed string you have to re calculate the height. but there is a quick fix which you don't need to calculate it your self. give the label a force line break at the end of your label in which case it has to re calculate the height automatically.

```
// see the \n at the end of your string that will cause the label to recalculate it's height.
let nameText = "My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer. My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer."`My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer. My name is Shreesha and Im an iOS developer. \n"
```

Comment: My question is it suppose to work even with the current implementation. But it seems that there is an issue with `NSAttributedString` or the `UILabel`. And I don't want to have a quick fix where the current implementation should work. But for now I did not add any attributed string inside the application just to release the build as soon as possible. And yes your suggestion works. But I want know what is the issue and I want it to work with the current implementation without any tweaks.

Comment: I did already explained to you that Xcode has a bug which can not calculate the exact size of the attributedString in case you try to  change the offset of any character. In that case you have to calculate the height of the label based on your string.